# Web Scraping with Rvest, Lapply, Rbind, and Selector Gadget

Tags: r, web-scraping, lapply, rvest

I am new to web scraping and am having difficulty scraping multiple pages within a website. I appreciate any feedback from the community!

**Goal:** To scrape each team's stats from 2019 cfbstats.com and to get each team's data into either one dataframe or custom team dataframes.

**Actions:** In the code below, I wrote an html call that pastes each team's (small example) unique identifier into the html code. Afterwards, I used an lapply function along with rvest to pull each team's data. Finally, rbind and do.call is used to join all the pulls.

**Issues:** After help from @Dave2e, I realized am getting issues with rbind combining all the data tables that were scraped. Any advice for joining the data tables from the web scrape? Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
names do not match previous names

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

team_id <- c(721, 5, 8)
teams <- paste('http://cfbstats.com/2019/team/', team_id, '/index.html', sep = "")

df_team_stats <- lapply(teams, function(i){
  webpage <- read_html(i)
  team_table <- html_nodes(webpage, '.team-statistics')
  overall_stats <- html_table(team_table)[[1]]
})

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, df_team_stats)
```

Comment: There were 2 different nodes with "class= team-statistics".  You just want the CSS to equal "table" and  the class= team-statistics.  Thus the proper call is: `html_nodes(webpage, 'table.team-statistics')`

Comment: Thank you @Dave2e! This is helping me get closer to the solution. Much appreciated. After plugging in your recommendation, I am finding I have some issues with my rbind.  'Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names'.

Comment: Use the `bind_rows()` function from the dplyr package.  It is a drop in  replacement for `do.call(rbind, ...)` plus it has the benefit of column name matching.

Comment: @Dave2e another great call. Thank you very much for all of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of issues here. Firstly, your `lapply` doesn't return a list of data frames, but a list of lists (it's just that each of the child lists has a data frame as its only contents).

Secondly, when you bind data frames together, they need to have the same column names. In your case, the team's name acts as a column name. If you just overwrite this, you won't know which team's data a row refers to, so you need to add a "team" column and standardise the names of the other columns:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

team_id <- c(721, 5, 8)
teams   <- paste('http://cfbstats.com/2019/team/', team_id, '/index.html', sep = "")

df_team_stats <- lapply(teams, function(i){
  webpage   <- read_html(i)
  all_stats <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath = "//table[@class='team-statistics']") %>%
               html_table() %>% `[[`(1)
  all_stats$team <- rep(names(all_stats)[2], nrow(all_stats))
  names(all_stats)[1:2] <- c("stat", "home")
  all_stats[,c(4, 1:3)]
})

as_tibble(bind_rows(df_team_stats))
#> # A tibble: 99 x 4
#>    team     stat                                   home          Opponents      
#>    <chr>    <chr>                                  <chr>         <chr>          
#>  1 Air For~ Scoring:  Points/Game                  34.1          19.8           
#>  2 Air For~ Scoring:  Games - Points               13 - 443      13 - 258       
#>  3 Air For~ First Downs:  Total                    286           216            
#>  4 Air For~ First Downs:  Rushing - Passing - By ~ 227 - 52 - 7  77 - 131 - 8   
#>  5 Air For~ Rushing:  Yards / Attempt              5.14          3.49           
#>  6 Air For~ Rushing:  Attempts - Yards - TD        755 - 3881 -~ 375 - 1307 - 11
#>  7 Air For~ Passing:  Rating                       187.92        141.25         
#>  8 Air For~ Passing:  Yards                        1602          2848           
#>  9 Air For~ Passing:  Attempts - Completions - In~ 126 - 68 - 6~ 377 - 238 - 7 ~
#> 10 Air For~ Total Offense:  Yards / Play           6.22          5.53           
#> # ... with 89 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Awesome stuff @AllanCameron This works flawlessly! If it is not too much trouble do you mind explaining how the following line of code works:
html_table() %>% `[[`(1)   ------ specifically the '[['(1) piece

Comment: Sure @DonnyDolio. This is simply a way of using the double bracket operator without disrupting the pipe and needing temporary variables. So instead of doing `B <- func(A);  B[[1]];` you can do `A %>% func() %>% '[['(1)`

Comment: Very cool @AllanCameron. Thanks for the explanation and all your help! It will be helpful to know moving forward!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe bind_cols() from dplyr could be useful here. So something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(rvest)

team_id <- c(721, 5, 8)
teams <- paste('http://cfbstats.com/2019/team/', team_id, '/index.html', sep = "")


df_team_stats <- lapply(teams, function(i){
  webpage <- read_html(i)
  team_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table.team-statistics')
  overall_stats <- html_table(team_table)[[1]] %>% 
    clean_names() %>% 
    column_to_rownames(var = "x")
})

finaldf <- df_team_stats %>% 
  bind_cols() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "Statistics")
```

Comment: Thanks @eugene100hickey. This is a cool solution to the problem. I appreciate your help and knowledge!